# Position of ''by agent''

Tags: passive-voice

> The boy was beaten **by** his mother for stealing money.
>
> The boy was beaten  for stealing  money **by** his mother.

Which sentence is better?Are there differences between these two sentences?

Comment: @Lawrence .Which is better ?Does the position of by agent in passive voice have  rules.

Comment: Why would you want to use passive voice if you want to say who the agent is? "His mother beat him for stealing money"

Comment: @JavaLatte For the same reason that everybody uses passive - so that the subject links to the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence could also mean the boy stole money that was near, or close to, his mother.

The first sentence is more general, and is more common, since it doesn't refer to any PARTICULAR money.

Answer (score 0):

I find the example's content somewhat troubling, so I'll change the specifics but keep the structure.

1. Jack was chased by Jill for spilling the water.
2. Jack was chased for spilling the water by Jill.

There are two verbs here: chase and spill.

When the agent (Jill) is placed in between the two verbs as in #1, the agent is strongly related to the first verb. Here, Jill does the chasing.

When the agent is placed after both verbs as in #2, it can be ambiguous which verb the agent is related to. It could mean the same as #1, or it could mean that someone else chased Jack because Jack spilled water next to Jill (using @user3235770's observation about "by").

So if the intent is to say that Jill does the chasing, use the first form.

Comment: OK, but in 2 you are also changing the definition of *by*, it is not just about the position. And I think most people would use "next to Jill" in your second situation.

Comment: @user3169 I take your point. I changed the interpretation of *by* in #2 because reading it as "by way of" or "by the agency of" didn't really sound fluent. Nevertheless, having two verbs and then an agent does set things up for ambiguity. E.g. "he was chased for her theft" vs " he was chased by her for theft" vs "he was chased for theft by her". The first two are clearly different, but the third could fit both situations. So the third is ambiguous. Structurally, the difference between the first pair and the third sentence is the position of the 'agent' in relation to the verbs.